# Rails - Active Admin - Wrong pluralized path - how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Active admin wrote the wrong path for my resource. I don't know how to change it. I googled that, read the documentation but I didn't find any solution.

I generated the Imagem resource

```
rails generate active_admin:resource Imagem
```

Browsed the admin page and got the following error:

```
localhost:3000/admin
gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/app/views/active_admin/dashboard/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `admin_imagems_path' for #<ActiveAdmin::MenuItem:0x00000006881f98>
```

That should be admin_imagens_path, but I don't know how to change it.

My inflactors.rb has the following

```
inflect.plural 'imagem', 'imagens'
inflect.singular 'imagens', 'imagem'
```

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can remember,

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections { |i| 
  i.irregular 'imagem', 'imagens' 
}
```

should work in both directions (singular to plural and plural to singular).